# Xamarin.Forms Java.exe exited with code 1

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've seen a few people encounter this issue with the heap size, which seems to be the issue in my case:

```
2>  Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap (TaskId:336)
```

I tried manually setting it to 1G:

[image]

Got the same error, realised the space required is actually greater than 1G (it's about 1.04GB), so I set it to 2G. But this just escalated the error:

```
1>  Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap (TaskId:305)
```

I thought I'd go nuclear and just set it to 10G, but then I got a different error saying it failed to create the Java VM.

In all honesty, I don't actually know what these mean, I'm just following along based on research of other SO and Xamarin Forums posts. Can anyone explain to me why I'm seeing these errors and how I can fix them?

Notes based on other questions: It's on debug, not release, and I don't have ProGuard ticked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to fix:

1. Select 64-bit Java SDK ([as per instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/update-jdk?tabs=windows))
2. Set heap size to 5G (as per screenshot in question)

Built and ran successfully after this.

Comment: 5GB holy moly! Simply switching from Oracle JDK x86 to MS Mobile JDK x64 worked for me.